# I got infinite loop in my React, Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

when I call .file store={store}  in my code, it make's infinite loop and make ram full, and i deleted it but need to call store or wrap with Provider, and i try to wrap with Provider store={store} and still infinite loop too, i wanna make project with redux but still confuse, so i try to follow some video in youtube, and i got this error

here is my App.js :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Lister from './Lister';
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Footer from './Footer.js'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Provider store={store}> // this store make infinite loop in my browser
          <div>
            <Lister />
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this is my store :

```js
import { createStore } from "redux";
import constants from './constants';

const initialState = {
    inputText: '',
    items: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('reducer', action);

    switch (action.type) {
        case constants.CHANGE_INPUT_TEXT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {inputText: action.text });
        case constants.ADD_ITEM:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                items: state.items.concat(state.inputText),
                inputText: ''
            });
        case constants.DELETE_ITEM: 
            const copyOfItems = state.items.slice()
            copyOfItems.splice(action.index, 1)
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: copyOfItems
            });
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

it happened when i make Footer, and the Footer need to call store={store}, but it makes stuck in browser

here is my Footer.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function Footer(props) {
    return (
        <Footer>
            Total count: {props.count}
        </Footer>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        count: state.items.length
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Footer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the `store`, it is the `Footer` component.

```
function Footer(props) {
    return (
        <Footer>
            Total count: {props.count}
        </Footer>
    )
}
```

You are trying to render `Footer` component inside the `Footer` component. Probably you tried to write `<div>` but your fingers did not listen to you.